# Does Ros2 Nav2 have a module for "teach and repeat?"

Tags: ros2, nav2

Wouldn't this be a good module to add to Nav2? The rover robot would be driven over a route and "learn" it, then repeat the performance through the navigation stack. Is anyone working on such a module?

Comment: if you thought of it, then other people also thought if it ... from all of those people, you can be certain that at least one of them has decided to work on it ... that is just an opinion in response to an opinion based question ... that is why opinion based questions are off topic here ... they do not produce very useful answers

Comment: your title question is good ... the other two are off topic here

Answer (score 1):

Not at this very moment, but its something I had planned to have added as part of a larger (but still not really all that large) development effort to provide documented GPS navigation support within Nav2 instead of the more 'wild west, figure it out yourself' that currently exists. Technically nothing about teach & repeat requires GPS, but that was the context I was planning on developing it under and I've not yet had a strong enough reason to work on it yet over more pressing needs.

If that would be something you'd be interested in working on or contributing, feel free to reach out!

Comment: Thanks for that! Yes, I have worked on it, and sampled the "lookahead_collision_arc" topic and attempted to navigate again based on that as input. But the simulation was "rehoming" its twist too much and wasting time instead of moving forward. Is there a setting that can be lowered to reduce this twisting tendency? I was using the "waypoints" module but want to try also the "poses" module for the repeat phase.